# 1980's DC Comic featuring Justice Society Anthology?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics

I'm trying to identify the first comic book I remember owning; It was a DC Comics comic, featuring the Justice Society of America, probably from (or reprinted in) the mid-1980's. It was a sort of anthology format, featuring various members of the Justice Society, each in their own stories. I think they stories might have built together to provide an overarching narrative.

Characters I believe had featured stories in it:

- The Flash/Jay Garrick
- Hourman/Rex Tyler
- Doctor Fate  (Presumably Kent Nelson?)

The one thing I most remember from it is that in the Doctor Fate story,  Fate was being attacked by some kind of pitch-black flowing antagonist (Shadow Thief?), and I remember that one of the panels featured his panicked eye peering out from under the encroaching blackness as he (whispered? invoked?)  "Nabu!"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that the story you remember is from [All-Star Squadron Annual #3](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/All-Star_Squadron_Annual_Vol_1_3)
  It was published on May 22, 1984.

In the story Ian Karkull, an old enemy of Doctor Fate had gained control over a dimension with shadowmagic, and used it to recruit some of the golden age archvillains for the Justice Society.

[image: The villains are assembled with Ian Karkull]

The Heroes quickly learned of this and attacked the villains they were most accustomed with  in small groups, most of the story is the heroes confronting the villains and taking care of them.

In the end it was up to Doctor Fate to confront Karkull himself. The villain had been transformed into a living shadow in an earlier adventure and was eager for revenge, which he took by engulfing Dr Fate in shadows and try absorb his soul.

[image: The shadow is attacking]

Dr Fate fights back by repeatedly trying to invoke Nabu.

[image: Invoking Nabu]

In the end Doctor Fate managed to summon the rest of the League and the Spectre bursted Karkull to pieces.

Comment: Looking through sources online... Doctor Fate's eye covered in shadow , desperately invoking "Nabu!" is on page 34, the page after the last one you posted. I definitely do remember a lot of trademarked logos in the issue, which is probably why I thought it was an anthology. I _think_ I do remember the golden-age Batmobile and the realistic cat-faced-mask Catwoman as featured in the issue. If there isn't another similar comic that features the eye of Fate, I think this is probably it, and will accept in a few days.

Comment: @notovny I added the page of the invoking too now for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly All Star Comics #3 (reprinted in 1975 as a "Famous first edition")

This is the first story featuring the Justice Society of America and as was usual for that series it features the different heroes in their own stories with framing sequences that tie them together.

Dr fate does indeed face a flowing black blob (but it's not the shadow thief - the Spectre story does have a living shadow that could easily be misremembered as the shadow thief)

I managed to find the issue online, but won't link due to the dubious legality of the source. (Couldn't see the bit you describe with the eye peering out)